# ARM Template - Validating parameters

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have created a simple JSON which creates a storage account. After I introduced a parameter of type object I am getting a validation error.

```
"parameters": {
  "storageAccountType": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
    "allowedValues": [
      "Standard_LRS",
      "Standard_GRS",
      "Standard_ZRS",
      "Premium_LRS"
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Storage Account type"
    }
  },
  "location": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "Australia East",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "Location for all resources."
    }
  }, "objectToConvert": {
    "type": "object"

}
```

Output from Octopus

```
{"storageAccountType":{"value":"Standard_LRS"},"location":{"value":"Australia East"},"objectToConvert":{"value":[{"a":"b"},{"c":"d"},{"c5":"d"},{"6a":"b"},{"cfg":"d"}]}}
```

I am sure the problem has been introduced due to the parameter objectToConvert.

The value of objectToConvert is being passed from Octopus and is

[image]

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after changing the data type from object to array